# ¿Cómo construir un Objeto (array asociativo) a partir de consultas relacionadas en LARAVEL 9?

Tags: laravel, api, postgresql, backend, laravel-9

Buenas tardes apreciados compañeros,
Tengo las siguientes tablas en mi base de datos (postgreSQL)
**credit_note**, **credit_note_detail**, **product** y **taxe**
lo que deseo hacer es lo siguiente cuando obtenga una nota de crédito esta deberá traer el detalle de la misma que se encuentra en la tabla credit_note_detail, ademas la tabla credit note detail debera contener los datos de product y taxe, actualmente hago lo siguiente.
en mi modelo CreditNote.php

```
public function creditNoteDetail(): HasMany{
            return $this->hasMany(CreditNoteDetail::class, 'credit_note' , 'id');
        }
```

y en mi controlador lo obtengo de la siguiente manera.

```
public function show($id)
    {
        $creditNote = CreditNote::with(['creditNoteDetail'])
            ->where('credit_note.id', '=', $id)
            ->first();

        $data = [
            'code' => Response::HTTP_OK,
            'credit_note' => $creditNote
        ];

        return response()->json($data, $data['code']);
    }
```

con esto obtengo lo siguiente:

```
{
  "code" : 200,
  "credit_note": {
    "id": 48,
    "resolution": 10,
    "credit_note_detail": [
      {
        "id": 46,
        "product": 12,
        "quantity": "1.00",
        "taxe": 3,
        "total": "294118.00",
        "credit_note": 48,
      },
      {
        "id": 47,
        "product": 11,
        "quantity": "1.00",
        "taxe": 3,
        "total": "7500.00",
        "credit_note": 48,
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

el tema es que quiero agregar los datos de la tabla product y taxe que se encuentran relacionadas en credit_note_detail al objeto credit_note_detail y obtenerlo de la siguiente manera.

```
{
  "code" : 200,
  "credit_note": {
    "id": 48,
    "resolution": 10,
    "credit_note_detail": [
      {
        "id": 46,
        "product": 12,
        "product_name" : "Computador portail ASUS",
        "product_reference" : "7w738399879",
        "quantity": "1.00",
        "taxe": 3,
        "taxe_name" : "IVA 19",
        "total": "294118.00",
        "credit_note": 48
      },
      {
        "id": 47,
        "product": 11,
        "product_name" : "Celular REDMI NOTE",
        "product_reference" : "7925w898",
        "quantity": "1.00",
        "taxe": 3,
        "taxe_name" : "IVA 19",
        "total": "7500.00",
        "credit_note": 48
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

de antemano muchas gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Comment: Puedes cargar relaciones anidadas como esta explicado en la documentacion [Nested Eager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#nested-eager-loading). Tendras que tener definidas esas relaciones en el modelo `CreditNoteDetail`, y te va a anidar eas otras relaciones dentro de cada CreditNoteDetail. El resultado esperado no es exactamente lo que muestras cuando dices "obtenerlo de la siguiente manera", para eso tendrias qu hacer join de las tablas

Comment: [Aqui](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#joins) la documentacion de `joins` para que le des una mirada. Intenta algo, y si no logras hacerlo funcionar como quieres, actualiza la pregunta con lo que hayas intentado y los errores o diferencias de lo que te da con el resultado que esperas